# Pontryagin class of a wedge product of vector bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $E\to M$ be a real vector bundle over a differentiable manifold $M$ and let $p_{1}(E)$ denote its first Pontryagin class. I would like to know if there is any formula allowing to write $p_{1}(\Lambda^2 E)$ in terms of $p_{1}(E)$. I am mostly interested in the case where the dimension of $M$ is less or equal than seven and $E=TM$ is the tangent bundle of the manifold. In particular, $p_{1}(TM)\in H^{4}(M,\mathbb{Z})$, and for the case that I am interested in, $H^{4}(M,\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and thus $p_{1}(TM) = k\, u$, where $k=0,\dots,9,$ and $u$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it is true that $\Lambda ^2(E\otimes \mathbb C)=(\Lambda^2E)\otimes \mathbb C$.

And for $n$-dimensional complex vector bundle $E'$ [splitting principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_principle) gives us $c_2(\Lambda^2E')=c_1(E')^2\cdot\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+c_2(E')\cdot(3n-3)$. So, maybe, $p(E)$ is not sufficient to compute $p_1(\Lambda^2E)$, because you have to know $c_1(E\otimes\mathbb C)$.

EDIT: for example, if $E$ is orientable, then $c_1(E\otimes \mathbb C)=0$, because we can induce $E$ from tautological bundle over oriented grassmannian $G_+(n,\infty)$, and $H^2(G_+(n,\infty))=0$.

Comment: Isn't $E\otimes \mathbb{C}$=$E\oplus \overline E$, so $c_1(E\otimes \mathbb{C})=0$

Comment: @Thomas, here $E$ is a real vector bundle, what do you mean by $\bar E$?

Comment: a right, I fail at reading... But still we can also say something if $H^2(M)$ does not contain any two torsion, as $2c_1(E\otimes \mathbb{C})=0$.

Comment: yes, if $H^2(M)\otimes\mathbb Z^2=0$ or $E$ is orientable, this summand will be zero.

Comment: We can assume that $E$ is orientable. Then, in that case, do we have $c_{2}(\Lambda^{2}E\otimes\mathbb{C}) = c_{2}(E\otimes\mathbb{C})\cdot (3n-3)$, where $n$ is the rank of $E\otimes\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Bilateral, i think so.